# How to install PyCharm Professional?

Tags: pycharm

I have bought a student license for my pycharm professional 4.0.5 and I would like to install it so that I can call it using dash home. How can I do that? Because everytime  I run the `pycharm.sh` it installs it and ask for my license information all over again. After installation, I can't find the location of installed pycharm. How can I find it? By the way I am using Xubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Dash Home, but since you're using Xubuntu, you can create an application shortcut for it via Launcher (create a new application with the sheet and plus instead of just the plus), specifying the exactly path of the folder you've extracted PyCharm to.

Here's how it would look (I've installed IntelliJ IDEA in a similar manner):

[image]